# Syntax for reduce in python

Tags: python

I attempted to emulate the structure of reduce from here: http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_fncs_map_filter_reduce.php

This is my code:

```
def collector(ix, myiter):
  s = reduce((lambda x,y: x + "," + y), myiter) #syntax error
  return s
```

The error is:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

This is surely a "gimme" for a python pro to answer.

Comment: Code looks ok and even runs ok. Can you provide full exception message with call stack?

Comment: I tried here too and it works

Comment: It looks like a bug in ipython.  It does work in python.  I am an UNHAPPY camper right now.

Comment: Weird. Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? As your link mentions, `reduce()` isn't built-in in Python 3, you need to import it from functools. But that shouldn't give you a Syntax error. I notice that your function doesn't use `ix`. Does ipython also give a syntax error if you leave that out? Eg, `def collector(myiter):` `return reduce(lambda x,y: x + "," + y, myiter)`. FWIW, I realise that you're experimenting with `reduce`, but you can do the same thing as your `collector()` with the built-in `str.join()` method - `','.join(myiter)`.

Comment: This is python 2. And there is no error in the python interpreter. There seems to be multiple bugs in ipython that are really hurting me.

Comment: I have no problem entering this into IPython 3.0.

Comment: Usually, IPython gives a pointer to the chacter where it realises the syntax is invalid; which character in your reduce line is that?